# Why does target not working here

Tags: javascript, html

First I make an index page containing frame and I named all frames as nasa google you tube etc .
then on search page

```
<input id="main_category_lan1" value="test" />
<a href="javascript:void(0)"
   onmouseover="
     window.open('http://nasasearch.nasa.gov/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&affiliate=nasa&query='
     +document.getElementById('main_category_lan1').value)", target="nasa">s</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)"
   onmouseover="window.open('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=lecture'
   +document.getElementById('main_category_lan1').value)",target="google">e</a>
```

but this is not working ,every time it open in new tab. Also I want to open both the pages bye a single button.
What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Please format your code properly

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask first read this buddy and format code clearly with  Actual you getting and What you are expecting

Answer (score 0):

Pass _self in target.

Read this link for more info about target

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_base_target.asp